# Best Practices For Minimizing number of queries with arrays

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a set of nested queries that (over time) will become way too intense as more data is entered into the database. I'm fairly new to working with anything other than basic queries, so take it easy on me please. I have read about joins, but those seem to have a similar performance hit. I believe I need to work with arrays here but I'm not sure how to go about that. Thanks for helping me learn!

```
$uid = $_SESSION['uid'];
// grab list of possible procedures
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT id,name,required FROM procedures ORDER BY name");
$stmt->execute();

////loop through each procedure and see how many have been done
foreach ($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $q) {
    $prid = $q['id'];
    //find sum of number completed in procedure log table
    //sql variables were cleaned earlier in code. I apparently cannot sum a column and fetch rows of data, so this query is redundant below
    $stmt2 = $dbh->prepare("SELECT sum(count) as cnt FROM procedure_log WHERE uid = '$uid' AND pid = '$prid' ORDER BY month"); 
    $stmt2->execute();
    $n = $stmt2->fetch();

    //print out list of completed procedures after the start date
    $stmt2 = $dbh->prepare("SELECT id,month,pid,other FROM procedure_log WHERE uid = '$uid' AND pid = '$prid' AND month > '2013-06-02' ORDER BY month");
    $stmt2->execute();

    //grab just number completed before the start date
    $stmt2 = $dbh->prepare("SELECT sum(count) as cnt FROM procedure_log WHERE uid = '$uid' AND pid = '$prid' AND month < '2013-06-02'");
    $stmt2->execute();  
    $o = $stmt2->fetch();
```

Comment: You're using variables `$uid` and `$prid` that you never assign. You shouldn't be interpolating variables at all, you should use placeholders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT p.id, p.name, p.required, l.month, sum(l.count) cnt
                       FROM procedures p
                       JOIN procedure_log l ON l.pid = p.id
                       WHERE l.uid = :uid
                       GROUP BY p.id, l.month
                       ORDER BY p.name, l.month");
$stmt->execute(array('uid' => $uid);
```

I suggest you do the counting and filtering of the rows before and after the start date in the loop that processes the results.

Comment: That's awesome. So much easier than working with multiple arrays too. Thank you!

Comment: Is it possible to have the cnt column and still print out each individual l.month? (Month is actually a misnomer here, it should be called date instead) i.e the second query in the foreach loop above.

Comment: Since `l.month` is in the `GROUP BY` clause, it's already printing each individual value.